# Performance of boost::mp11::mp_with_index compared to array of std::function

Tags: c++, boost, callback, benchmarking, std-function

Consider the following two snippets:

```
// Option (1).
boost::mp11::mp_with_index<N>(i,
                              [&](const auto i){ function<i>(/* args... */); });
```

and

```
// Option (2).
inline static const std::array<std::function<void(/* Args... */)>, N>
    functionArray{function<0>, ..., function<N-1>};
functionArray[i](/* args... */);
```

where `N` is a compile time size approximately in the range [0, 20], `i` is a runtime index between `0` and `N-1`, and `template <size_t I> function(/* Args... */)` is a template function with a known signature. **Which of the two options is the fastest one?**

Note: I know that `boost::mp11::mp_with_index` basically creates a switch statement that allows to convert a runtime index to a compile time one. This introduces some indirection, but I expect this to not be too costly. Similarly, I know that `std::function` introduces some indirection due to type erasure. My question is: which of the two indirection kinds is the most efficient?

Comment: The only way to know is to measure it in real code. Where is `std::function` in your code examples?

Comment: @Evg Thanks for pointing it out, I have just edited my question! I was wondering whether the kind of indirection implemented by `std::function` is as efficient as the one afforded by `boost::mp11::mp_with_index`. To me, it looks like it can hardly be the case because `std::function` does not know about `N`, so it cannot create a compile time table with all possible implementations with signature `void(/* Args... */)`. Does anyone know how `std::function` work under the hood?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::array<std::function<void(Args...)>, N>` is likely to introduce some overhead compared to an array of pure pointers `std::array<void(*)(Args...), N>`.

Looking at the generated assembly at https://godbolt.org/z/a8z9aKs7P, the following observations can be made:

`boost::mp11::mp_with_index` is compiled to a branch table that holds N addresses for N different instructions that simply call `function<I>` when jumped to. So, it will look for an address in the branch table, jump to that address, and then jump again to the desired function.

This branch table could be simplified by having it simply store the addresses of `function<I>`, only needing one jump. This *is* what happens when you have an array of function pointers, the array essentially being a branch table.

`std::function` is similar, but calling a `std::function` is slightly more complicated than calling a regular function pointer.

---

Note clang is horrible at optimising this at `-O2` and even `-O3`. `boost::mp11::mp_with_index<N>` is actually a bunch of if/else statements that should be very easy to compile as if it was a `switch`, but clang fails to do that (and left with `N` "compare and conditional jump" instructions). The array of function pointers is the only good option here.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer! In other words, the most efficient option is an array of function pointers! But what if the functions I am interested in are member functions of heterogeneous classes? In this case they could not be stored in function pointers. What would the best option be in this case?

Comment: Is it safe to say that in the general case of member functions of heterogeneous classes (which cannot be stored in function pointers), then the best option would be to store them in an array of `std::function` compared to the _Boost_ approach? Why is this the case? Indeed, as I pointed out in a comment to the main question, `std::function` uses less information compared to the _Boost_ approach.

Comment: @fdev You can use pointer-to-member functions, or wrap them in lambdas that can convert to member functions. The Boost approach will generate slightly less code (the `std::function` has code for its static initializer and `sizeof(std::function<void(Args...)> == 32` so it takes space to actually store the array, whereas `mp_with_index` only generates a pair of jumps), but will probably have similar performance to array of std::function, you would have to benchmark to make sure.